# CKEDITOR instances not recognized in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am adding new textarea elements via AJAX, so I wrote the function assignRichText() below which adds CKEDITOR to any textarea.addckeditor, then removes the addckeditor class so it isn't added a second time later. This seems to work.

However, I am also calling the function updateRichText() below when doing AJAX saves, because otherwise my textarea elements are not updated (since I'm not submitting the form). In my console I see that the function is starting and ending, however the console.log('i='+i); never puts anything in my console. So my instances are not being picked up. Is there something wrong with my "for" statement?

```
function assignRichText(){
    $('textarea.addckeditor').each(function(){
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('textarea.addckeditor'), {
                toolbar: ['bold', 'italic']
            })
                .then(editor => {
                    console.log(editor);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

        $(this).removeClass('addckeditor');
    });
}

function updateRichText(){
    console.log('start updateRichText');

    for (var i in ClassicEditor.instances){
        console.log('i='+i);
        ClassicEditor.instances[i].updateElement();
    }

    console.log('end updateRichText');
}
```

Comment: The only thing I have found that 100% updates all instances is to submit the form. So perhaps I can submit the form via Javascript and then cancel the default action?

Comment: so if you run ClassicEditor.instances in console, what will happen ?

Comment: If I put ClassicEditor.instances in my console, the return is "undefined".

Comment: Don't understand why that would be. So I think my options are to (1) figure out what's wrong with ClassicEditor.instances, (2) always do a submit form (and immediately cancel the default action) which seems to update them fine, or (3) create my own update function to copy the contents from the <div> to the <textarea> manually.

Comment: I am using CK Editor 5

Comment: I think CK Editor 5 might be the problem. I can't find any documentation on how to update the <textarea> element via Javascript. All the docs I am finding I think are for CK Editor 4.

Comment: function updateRichText(){
 var insertText;

 $('.ck-editor__editable').each(function(){
  insertText=$(this).html();
  $(this).closest('.lineitem').find('.isckeditor').val(insertText);
 });
}